# Android Activity Switching back and forth

Tags: performance, android-activity

I have 3 activities: 
MainActivity, MovieActivity and ActorActivity.

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to understand how to implement the transitions between each activity by making sure I don't start n number of activities and run out of memory.

Here is the scenario the user may go through:

MainActivity(Lists Movies) ---> MovieActivity Starts on clicking a Movie and displays actors ---> ActorActivity starts if you click on a actor.

Now, in the actor activity i display the list of movies the actor stars in and so the user can potentially go back to the same movie from which he came to the current actor activity. And this can keep going on forever back and forth or basically switching between Movie and Actor activities on and on.

I've set the parent activity of both MovieActivity and ActorActivity to MainActivity, so hitting the top UP button at any time will list back all the movies.

What is the best way to handle this scenario? When user hits back button I'm not sure what the ideal behavior should be if the back trace is MovieA <--> ActorA back and forth like say 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code on Back Button Press.

```
  @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

          Intent i = new Intent(currentactivity, targaetactivity);
          startActivity(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the history manually and find a meaningful wait to go back, e.g. back to previous screen unless you have loops of MovieA/ActorA/MovieB/ActorB. Then implement manually the onBackPressed method.
This way you always finish your activity when you switch to another and you just store in a stack the activity parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the previous detail when you transition to a new detail page and pass it as an extra to the new activity (ie: when going from Actor -> Movie you should pass the name of the Actor in an Intent extra). Then, if the user wants to transition from the Movie page to an Actor page you can compare it to see if this is the same Actor as the previous one (the one passed in the extra). If this is so, instead of launching a new Activity, you just call `finish()` which will return the user to the previous Actor detail page.

In this way you will prevent making nonsense loops (A->B->A->B) bit still allow the user to go from A->B->D->E->T->Q if he wants to.

Comment: Thanks David, this seems logical and might be the best route for me to go. I'll implement it and see how it goes. On a related note, is it ok to keep starting new activities using intent and not end up consuming more and more  memory? Is there an easy way for me to check the memory usage of my app over time? For instance, as you mentioned, if a user goes A->B->D->E->T->Q say 100 levels down, will the back stack maintain such a deep level?(ie if i hit back 100 times i should come back to MainActivity A). Any performance considerations i should keep in mind? Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Every time you create a new activity instance you will consume memory. How much depends a lot on how you've programmed it and what you have in your Views. You can keep track of your memory usage by using various methods on the `Debug` class. Yes, the back stack will keep track of 100 levels or more of activities, but you may end up consuming too much memory in this case and your app will just crash. It might make more sense for you to manage this "back stack" yourself and not continue to infinitely create new Activity instances.